# Use $ and $elemMatch to group entities

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Considering the following document in my mongo DB instance :

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "people": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "bar"},
    /.../
  ],
  "stats": [
    {"peopleId": 1, "workHours": 24},
    {"peopleId": 2, "workHours": 36},
    /.../
}
```

Each element in my collection represent the work of every employee in my company, each weeks. As an important note, `peopleId` may change from one week to another !

I would like to get all weeks where `foo` worked more than 24 hours. As you can see, the format is kinda annoying since the people name and the work hours are separated in my database. A simple `$and` is not enough.

I wonder if, using some `$` and `$elemMatch` I can achieve doing this query.
Can I use this to group the "people" entities with "stats" entities ?

Comment: I saw it is not possible to use `$in` to filter by objects, so I have some doubts it is possible :/

Comment: I think you might need [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction) which can provide a 'join' during the aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Query to get `foo` worked more than 24 hours.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind: { path : "$people"}},
{$unwind: { path : "$stats"}},
{$match: { "people.name" : "foo"}},
{$group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            peopleIdMoreThan24: { $addToSet: { 
                $cond : { if : { $and : [ {"$eq" :  ["$people.id", "$stats.peopleId" ] }, 
                         {"$gt" : ["$stats.workHours", 24] }]}  , then : "$people.id", else: "Not satisfying the condition"}}}             
        }
},
{$unwind: { path : "$peopleIdMoreThan24" }},
{$match: { "peopleIdMoreThan24" : {$nin : [ "Not satisfying the condition"]}}},
]);
```

**Data in collection:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ],
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "peopleId" : 1,
            "workHours" : 24
        }, 
        {
            "peopleId" : 2,
            "workHours" : 36
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ],
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "peopleId" : 1,
            "workHours" : 25
        }, 
        {
            "peopleId" : 2,
            "workHours" : 36
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ],
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "peopleId" : 1,
            "workHours" : 25
        }, 
        {
            "peopleId" : 2,
            "workHours" : 36
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:-**

The output has document id and people id of `foo` worked more than 24 hours.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "peopleIdMoreThan24" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "peopleIdMoreThan24" : 1
}
```